# Where in the Eigen source is the sum() function defined for a particular matrix?

Tags: c++, eigen

I am new to Eigen and trying to get a feel for the layout. I noticed that each matrix has a sum() function that returns the sum of all the coefficients in a given matrix. I was interested in how it was implemented, since I wanted to find the best way to loop through an eigen matrix. I went into the source code and found the following interface in "DenseBase.h": 
`EIGEN_DEVICE_FUNC Scalar sum() const;`
Perhaps I misunderstood how Eigen is designed, but I thought it was the case that all functions were defined in their header files. I also looked in "Matrix.h" and "MatrixBase.h", and was unable to find the implementation. Which header file is the definition in?

Answer (score 2):

The `sum()` function comes from `Eigen::internal::scalar_sum_op<Scalar>()` being called through `redux` in Redux.h.  scalar_sum_op is defined in Functors.h.  After that I lost interest.  I found this two ways.  The first was to use Visual Studio and right click on `sum()` and choosing "Go to Definition", following the trail until I was satisfied.  The second was to use grep searching for `sum()` and again following the trail.

If you read through Redux.h you will get a feel for how the developers did it.  They spend considerable effort vectorizing and unrolling things to make them work fast.  I would say the best way to loop through an Eigen matrix is to use the provided interfaces to do what you want.  I doubt you have a use case that has not been covered by the interface somehow.

Comment: Right, I confirm that the relevant piece of code is in `src/Core/Redux.h`, but you definitely don't want to reproduce it, just call `mat.redux(...)` with you own functor in case it's not already covered by Eigen's API.